# Why it is not printing ten asterisks in the last line when using range (1,10) in the for loop?

Tags: python

```
for i in range(1,10):
    print("*"*i)
```

I don't know why it is printing 9 asterisks in the last line. Please help me with this

Comment: `print(list(range(1, 10)))` might give you a hint

Answer (score 1):

`range(1, 10)` runs from `1` to `9` both inclusive.

You need to use `range(1, 11)` if you want to iterate from `1` to `10`.

```
for i in range(1,11): 
    print("*"*i)
```

Answer (score 0):

The Answer for this is

```
for i in range(0, 10):
      print("*" * i)
```

or

```
for i in range(1, 11):
      print("*" * i)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in the range function , suppose we have given (1,n)
Then we will only get values till (n-1).
To have 10 * in the last line , update the range function as (1,11).
Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to krishna's answer you can alternatively use this code.

```
for i in range(10): 
  print("*"*(i+1))
```

`i` values start from 0 and end at 9. You can just see the number in range() argument as no. of iterations you want. You should just change `i` to `i+1` in print() because you are starting from 0 and the first line will be empty if you keep it as `i`

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
for i in range(1,10):
    print("*"*i)  // Takes the string value "*" Then multiples each line by the range
```

While that is what it looks like for me is that it is taking i and storing it as a range, then taking the string "*" and runs a for loop until 10 and multiples the string value by the range i hence why you're output probably looks like this.

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*******
********
*********
>>> 
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

For output of `range(a, b)`, the very first element is `a` and the very last element is `b-1`.
Here, `list(range(1, 10)) = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

To correct it, you can use:

`for i in range(1, 11): print("*"*i)`